# Virtualbox in a Ubuntu Docker Container is missing Kernel Headers

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant, docker

I'm trying to run virtualbox in Docker for the use of vagrant. I try to achieve that with Ubuntu.
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib'
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget linux-headers-generic
RUN wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc virtualbox dkms virtualbox-dkms
RUN wget https://dl.bintray.com/mitchellh/vagrant/vagrant_1.7.1_x86_64.deb
RUN dpkg -i vagrant_1.7.1_x86_64.deb
```

If I then run `virtualbox`, I get:

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
         Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
         headers, most likely linux-headers-.

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
Failed to open the X11 display!
```

As you see, I'm already trying to install my headers with `apt-get install linux-headers-generic`.
But trying to install with uname:
    apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
doesn't work:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.16.7-tinycore64
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.16.7-tinycore64'
```

I can't find the linux-headers-3.16.7-tinycore64 anywhere. Googled it etc., don't find it, even on the linux tinycore website.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the kernel module on your host system, not in the docker image.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic virtualbox-dkms
```

Then test if the kernel module is loaded:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/virtualbox status
VirtualBox kernel modules are loaded.
```

Then you should be able to run the docker container by mounting /dev/vboxdrv:

```
docker run -it -v /dev/vboxdrv:/dev/vboxdrv image-name
```

See [VirtualBox Inside Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/jencryzthers/vboxinsidedocker/~/dockerfile/) on Docker Hub for an example.